# Yum doesn't show all installed packages

Tags: linux, installation, centos, package, yum

I have logstash installed on one of my CentOS 7 hosts. When I run the `sudo yum list installed` command, it is not on the list. When I try to install logstash, yum offers me a fresh install. What could be the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Probably logstash was installed manually then, and not by `yum`/`rpm`. You can check this by asking `rpm` (which is used by `yum` under the hood):

```
rpm -qf /path/to/logstash-binary
```

translation: to which package does `/path/to/logstash-binary` belong. Then you'll know if it belongs to an `rpm` package. If not, that means the binary was installed in some other way (unzipping, ...). `rpm` (and hence `yum`) has no knowledge of any files not installed by an `rpm` package.